# Foremost file naming - Recovery of file names from inodes

Tags: data-recovery, inode, forensics

I have been asked to recover some files from a corrupt Linux partition. The partition data is shot to pieces but i have been able to locate the file names and the associated Inode number.

Using Foremost i was able to recover the data (A folder full of pdf's), [Foremost](http://foremost.sourceforge.net/) (as expected) has named the files as 6 digit hex values.

My question is... What are the numbers that Foremost uses to name the file? Are they `inode` numbers? Addresses? Just unique numbers?

Comment: If I read the source code correctly, it should be the block number `u_int64_t       block = ((t_offset) / s->block_size)`

Comment: @frostschutz Indeed, looking at the source code here too, it appears to be the block number. The manpage hints at that, too. You should post that as an answer.